# How to make sure any two points with small enough distance are inside a common open set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $K$ be a compact subset of a metric space, and I cover $K$ with finite open sets. How can I select $\delta>0$, such that for any $x,y\in K$, with $d(x,y)
<\delta$, $x,y$ are inside an open set?

---

I get this question when I try to show for any compact subset $K$ of a Riemannian manifold $M$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ s.t.$\forall y,z\in K$ with $d(y,z)<\epsilon$, then there exists a minimizing geodesic joining $y,z$. My approach is covering $K$ by totally normal neighborhood $W_\alpha$ of finitely many points in $K$, and what I have to do is to select small enough $\epsilon$, such that any two points with distance less that $\epsilon$ are inside a common totally normal neighborhood.

I think this can be done since I only need to make sure the points are sufficiently far away from the boundary. Could you help me to find a rigorous argument? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand the question, you can cover $K$ by finitely many open balls of radius $2\delta$. If $d(x,y)<\delta$, and $x\in B(x_0,2\delta)$, then by the triangle inequality you get $d(y,x_0)\leq d(y,x)+d(x,x_0)<2\delta$.

Comment: Lebesgue covering lemma might come in handy here too.

Comment: @DimitriosNt Why do you have the last inequality?

Comment: I have to be more careful. Cover $K$ by balls of radius $\delta$, and then let the family of open sets be the enlarged balls of radius $2\delta$. If $d(x,y)<\delta$, then $d(x,x_0)<\delta$ for some $x_0$, so $d(y,x_0)\leq d(y,x)+d(x,x_0)<2\delta$, and both $x,y$ are in the same ball of radius $2\delta$.

Comment: @DimitriosNt Thanks. Now it's clear.